# getting coordinates of a visual block via Neovim API

Tags: vim, neovim

I am browsing through the list of available functions in Neovim Python Client API in search of a way to get coordinates of a visual mode selection.  Something that would give me a pair of (row #,column #) of a visual block start/end.

So far, i haven't found anything explicit that would allow me to do so.  Maybe someone has?

**EDIT:**

As suggested in comments below, I have tried using the vim native `getpos` function in the following way:

```
from neovim import attach

nvim = attach('child', argv=["/bin/env","nvim","--embed"])
buffer = nvim.current.buffer
buffer[0] = 'visual mode' 
nvim.feedkeys("fmve")
print("Current caret position: {}".format(nvim.windows[0].cursor))
cmd ='getpos("\'<")' # cmd=r"""getpos("'<")"""
print("Start of visual selection: {}".format(nvim.eval(cmd)))
```

The result of running the script above is:

```
Current caret position: [1,10] 
Start of visual selection: [0,0,0,0]
```

I would expect the values of the second printed line should be something like:

```
Start of visual selection: [1,8]
```

given that we are asking for the selection start location.  Where am I getting this wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't neovim still supporting vim functions -> `getpos("'<")`...

Comment: I have migrated this question to [Vi/Vim stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14333/getting-coordinates-of-a-visual-block-via-neovim-python-api) where it probably belongs.